# anyone can help me to use material icons in react project

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, modulenotfounderror

I have imported two material icons packages

```
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2"
```

but the code is not working it shows me errors like a module not found so what do I need to do?

```
    npm install @material-ui/icons
    npm install @material-ui/core
```

i have installed abowe two packeges.

[below is the error of my project]

[image]

Comment: You have installed version of material ui v4 (@material-ui/icons) , and in your code you import mui v5: @mui/icons-material

Comment: no i have letest version of both    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",

Comment: Yeah you have the latest version of mui v4.. 
If you want to keep using it you should check the v4 documentation and import here :
https://v4.mui.com/components/material-icons/#material-icons

Comment: thanq it's worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Material UI with v5 did a [rebranding](https://mui.com/blog/material-ui-is-now-mui/) to move away from just "material" and is now called "MUI".

This means, their npm packages have too been renamed.
If you goto [@material-ui/core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/core) in npm you can see this notice

> This package has been deprecated
> You can now upgrade to @mui/material. See the guide: https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/

In this case, assume you are importing icons as suggested in https://mui.com/components/material-icons which uses v5 where as installed packages are v4 (with @material scope)

You have couple of options:

- upgrade all packages to v5 (ie, @mui scope) if you want to use mui v5. Do note, you have to install couple of additional dependencies as well - `@emotion/react @emotion/styled` as MUI is now based on emotion.
- or, update import to `@material-ui/icons` as mentioned here - https://v4.mui.com/components/material-icons/

Answer (score 0):

I guess the new way to install material UI is `npm install @mui/icons-material`. try it out.
[image]